# Localized Splash screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, localization, splash-screen, default.png

Is it possible to have different image for different language for Splash screen in iPhone ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can localize the Default.png file like you would localize any other. That way, depending on the device language the appropriate Default.png is used.

Might I add, that splash screens are highly dissuaded in the HIG, your Default.png should look like the first screen to give the illusion your app starts up faster. I haven't heard of apps being rejected due to a splash screen on the other hand.

**Edit**

You can not add some kind of custom behavior which decides which Default.png to use. Either you localize the file or you use a Default.png with no text in it.

Comment: Yes Yannick its true, but i think apple should provide this facility just like how they allow different images for devices like iPhone 3g, iPhone 4 and iPad by using prefix and postfix in the filename.

Comment: That's the point, you can have different images for different languages even in combination with retina versions. Don't really know what you mean?

Comment: Sure you can, I haven't tested it, but I'm sure you can have both a normal and retina version of the Default.png image per language.

Comment: That sounds good, i will search for the solution and if i get any will post it here, and if you have any please let me know.

Comment: I have just tried to localize the Default.png but it always showed the old image. After cleaning the project and deleting the app in the simulator and reinstalling it worked fine!

Comment: I try to localize Default.png, but when submitting the App to App Store, it shows warning that Default.png does not exist in project folder ( i put it in en.lproj & other localized .lproj folder ). How to resolve ?

Comment: I noticed that people are talking about deleting the whole app from either the device or the simulator, and then rebuilding and deploying from scratch to correctly show localized Default images. While this does appear to fix the problem, I found that it continues to happen for existing users after they update to your new, localized version on the App Store. Unless those users will also delete the app and re-download, you'll find that they're getting the old, non-localized image just like you did before deleting and reinstalling.