# Runtime splash screen iPhone

Tags: iphone, splash-screen

I made a iPhone application which supports French and English languages. When application is loading there is black screen appears initially. Instead of this I want to add splash screens for French and English. Both splash screens are different. When language is French it will load French splash screen and when language is English, it will load English splash screen.

In simple words, How I add Default.png for English and French?

Please let me know if there is any way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically load a universal screen, then switch it up with one of your language specific screens. You can play with this code:

Add this to your `AppDelegate.m`

```
@interface SwitchDefault : UIViewController {}
@end
@implementation SwitchDefault

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* use an if statement here to display a specific French / English spash  */ 
    UIImageView *switch = @"English.png";    
    self.view = switch;  

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(imageDidFadeOut:finished:context:)];
    /*  add a fade into your app  */
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
- (void)imageDidFadeOut:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
@end
```

And in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` do thig:

```
SwitchDefault * switch = [[[SwitchDefault alloc] init] autorelease];
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window addSubview:switch.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late. You can localize the Default.png file. See http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/08/19/localization-your-iphone-os-applications-in-xcode/ for the procedure (procedure in link is for text files, but same can be done for images).

I've created localized app icons using this method, and works perfectly.

Comment: see also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880046/localized-splash-screen-in-iphone